# Cache in liferay

Tags: xml, caching, liferay, liferay-6

I have problem with liferay cache, so the problem is that when my cache ExpirationTime expires portlet on refresh go to doView() method and there i have if statment which is go to xml and return true/false if xml is updated. So if xml isnt updated i give a cache a new setExpirationTime... but on the page portlet doesnt show anything.. Cache is work fine.. my refreshing in 5 minuts doestn update doView method so the problem is with if statment and this render.Response...

this is source(example):

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)throws IOException, PortletException {

if(!isItNew(renderRequest,renderResponse)){
    //FALSE
    //must to add time to cache 
    renderResponse.getCacheControl().setUseCachedContent(true);
    renderResponse.getCacheControl().getExpirationTime(100);
}else{
    //TRUE
    //call xml and send to view
    include(viewJSP,renderRequest,renderRequest);
}
```

And method

```
private boolean isItNew(RenderRequest renderRequest,RenderResponse renderResponse) {
//go to XML and return true or false
return false;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test with this portal.properties value:

```
#
# Specify the number of minutes before a session expires. This value is
# always overridden by the value set in web.xml.
#
session.timeout=30
```

And related value into web.xml.